# CSS not working on Facebook page

Tags: html, css, facebook, fbml

For some reason, the rollover CSS I'm using won't work through Facebook's rendering engine. Am I doing something wrong or is there just an inherent problem with certain CSS properties on custom Facebook pages? Here's my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://epandits.com/topdish/newCascadeStyleSheet1.css" type="text/css" />

<table id="wrapper">
    <tr>
        <td class="imgcontainer">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://www.bigjimsburgers.com/burger.jpg" alt="" />
                <span class="desc">
                    Very long text that wraps around and is centered properly
                </span>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td class ="imgcontainer">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://www.bigjimsburgers.com/burger.jpg" alt="" />
                <span class="desc">
                    Very long text that wraps around and is centered properly
                </span>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="imgcontainer">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://www.bigjimsburgers.com/burger.jpg" alt="" />
                <span class="desc">
                    Very long text that wraps around and is centered properly
                </span>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td class ="imgcontainer">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://www.bigjimsburgers.com/burger.jpg" alt="" />
                <span class="desc">
                    Very long text that wraps around and is centered properly
                </span>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you were given a -1 on this question.

Answer (score 0):

maybe do without css with something crazy like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ColbyGold/KfZmc/

Comment: That's pretty cool, but I'd really like to have the rollover text and opacity switch... Any ideas?